# What is the 90th derivative of $\cos(x^5)$ where x = 0?

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, derivatives, taylor-expansion

Trying to figure out how to calculate the 90th derivative of $\cos(x^5)$ evaluated at 0.  This is what I tried, but I guess I must have done something wrong or am not understanding something fundamental:

$\cos(x) = \displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^\infty \dfrac{(-1)^n}{(2n)!} {(x)}^{2n}$

$\cos(x^5) = \displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^\infty \dfrac{(-1)^n}{(2n)!} {(x^5)}^{2n}=$

$1-\dfrac{{x^{5\cdot2}}}{2!}+\dfrac{{x^{5\cdot4}}}{4!}-\dfrac{{x^{5\cdot6}}}{6!}+...-\dfrac{{x^{5\cdot18}}}{18!}+...-\dfrac{{x^{5\cdot90}}}{90!}+...+\dfrac{{x^{5\cdot190}}}{180!}+...$

$f(x) = \displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^\infty \dfrac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!} \cdot {x^{n}} $

$\dfrac{f^{90}(0)}{90!}\cdot {{x^{90}}} = -\dfrac{{x^{5\cdot18}}}{18!}$

${f^{90}(0)} = -\dfrac{90!}{18!}$

[Wolfram](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=90th%20derivative%20of%20cos%28x%5E5%29%20at%20zero) has it at some really large negative number.

Comment: Careful, $(x^5)^m = x^{5m}$ and not $x^{5^m}$.

Comment: Your method, with suitable correction,  will work. Note that $(x^5)^{18}=x^{90}$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Thanks guys, I was able to fix it with the algebraic mistake orangeskid pointed out and the tip Andre gave.

Comment: Your current answer, $f^{(90)}(0) = \dfrac{90!}{18!}$, is missing a negative sign.

Comment: @JimmyK4542 Or rather $-1^{9}=-1$, I like how you wrote out your answer; it is more clear there that $x^{90}$ is found only when $n=9$

Comment: Nobody mentioned Faa di Bruno's formula or Bell polynomials. I'm disappointed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taylor series is the right way to go, however, you need to be careful in how you obtain the Taylor series for $\cos x^5$.

Since $\cos \theta = \displaystyle\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}\dfrac{(-1)^n\theta^{2n}}{(2n)!}$, we have $f(x) = \cos x^5 = \displaystyle\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}\dfrac{(-1)^n(x^5)^{2n}}{(2n)!} = \displaystyle\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}\dfrac{(-1)^nx^{10n}}{(2n)!}$

The $x^{90}$-coefficient is found only in the $n = 9$ term, so we have $\dfrac{f^{(90)}(0)}{90!}x^{90} = \dfrac{(-1)^9x^{90}}{18!}$.

Now, just solve for $f^{(90)}(0)$.

Comment: Thanks this is essentially what I was trying to do, but made several simple mistakes, I completely understand it now thanks to you guys.

Answer (score 1):

$$\cos(x^5) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \dfrac{(-1)^n}{(2n)!} {(x^5)}^{2n}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \dfrac{(-1)^n}{(2n)!} x^{10n}$$

To get the coefficient of $x^{90}$ in this series, just put $n=9$ to get $\dfrac{(-1)^9}{18!}$ (I think this is where you went wrong). Now if you differentiate the series $90$ times, and set $x=0$, the only non-zero term is
$$\dfrac{(-1)^990!}{18!}$$

Comment: The $90!$ seems on the wrong place.

Comment: This is definitely the right way to do it, but you need to put the $90!$ where it belongs, as @egreg has already pointed out.

Comment: Yes, thanks $-$ I've fixed it now.